# VC++ does not show output

Tags: visual-c++, trigonometry

I am new to VC++ and its been a few times now, and this is the third program that does not give output even after it is build succesfully.

```
 #include <AFXWIN.H>
 #include <math.h>
 #define PI 3.1415926
 #define SEGMENTS 500

 class CMyApp : public CWinApp {
public:
   virtual BOOL InitInstance();
};

class CMainWindow : public CFrameWnd
{
public:
CMainWindow();
protected:
afx_msg void OnPaint();
afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT, CPoint);
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP();
};

CMyApp myAPP;
    BOOL CMyApp::InitInstance() {
    m_pMainWnd = new CMainWindow;
    m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_MAXIMIZE);
    m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();
    return TRUE;
  }

 BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP (CMainWindow, CFrameWnd)
 ON_WM_PAINT ()
 END_MESSAGE_MAP ()

 CMainWindow::CMainWindow() {
     Create(NULL,"The Hello Application",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);                                                           
}

void CMainWindow::OnPaint() {
    CRect rect;
    int nWidth = rect.Width();
    int nHeight = rect.Height();

CPaintDC dc (this);
CPoint aPoint[SEGMENTS];
for (int i =0; i < SEGMENTS; i++){
    aPoint[i].x = ((i*nWidth)/SEGMENTS );
    aPoint[i].y= (int)((nHeight/2)* (1-(sin((2*PI*i)/SEGMENTS))));
}
dc.Polyline(aPoint, SEGMENTS);
UpdateData(false);
 }
```

The above program should give Sine curve as the output, except that I get a blank window. And I don't know why does it happen. If it helps, I am using VC++ 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that the rectangle you use to get the width and height is not initialized. You have to get the rectangle from somewhere, see e.g. [`CWnd::GetClientRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkzy4k3x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).